# Java Eclipse console output String variable wrong direction

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse Helios on Java 7 and Apache Tomcat 7.0. I have a huge SQL query that contains many temp table such as:

```
String query = 
"\n select * " +
"\n from  " +
"\n ( " +
"\n       select *  " +
"\n       from a " +
"\n       inner join " +
"\n       ( " +
"\n             ...
"\n       )total on total.pk = a.pk " +
"\n ) data "
"\n inner join x on x.pk = a.pk
"\n inner join y on y.fk = a.pk
"\n inner join z on z.fk = a.pk
"\n inner join zz on zz.fk = a.pk
```

I'm using Tab button to forward a distance but the console output doesn't display a right direction like my query before. The output may likes:

```
select * 
from 
(
...
)data
inner join x...
               inner join y...
inner join z...
               inner join zz...
```

The output has many wrong distance like that, make me different to read or fix... Because of using tab or my Eclipse version or other? Please give me an advice, thank so much.

Comment: Try using `\t` for tabs.

Comment: Your tab spacement in Eclipse might be different (4) than the standard 8 that the console uses. Replace it with spaces, you can let Eclipse do that for you via the preferences,  or use `\t` in the string so you won't get confused.

Comment: what exactly is the issue and what exactly is the question?

Comment: It's same issue when I'm using above \n\t or \r\n...

Comment: @M.leRutte, no other way sir?

Comment: @Stultuske, the query and output are not same, makes me hard to fix or read it.

Comment: @mmo2112 the query as you posted it wouldn't even compile, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Stultuske,
Sir, it's not about the query can be compiled or not. The problem is my String variable contains huge characters, so I must to separate it to multi lines with correct format for easily maintaining! I think you don't understand my question (not like 2 upper people), I'm sorry so much because of my grammar and wasting your time. Best regards.